# String literal concatenation fails when prefixed string is adjacent to non-prefixed string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

In MSVS2013, which I believe to be C++11 compliant, the compiler doesn't like the following:

```
LPCTSTR str = _T("boo " "hoo");
```

which translates to:

```
wchar_t const * str = L"boo " "hoo";
```

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (which I know is not definitive, but it's the only reference I have at the moment):

- String literals placed side-by-side are concatenated during compilation. That is, "Hello,"  " world!" yields the (single) string "Hello, world!".

  - If the two strings have the same encoding prefix (or neither has one), the resulting string will have the same encoding prefix (or no prefix).
  - ***If one of the strings has an encoding prefix and the other doesn't, the one that doesn't will be considered to have the same encoding prefix as the other.***
  - If a UTF-8 string literal and a wide string literal are side by side, the program is ill-formed.
  - Any other combination of encoding prefixes may or may not be supported by the implementation. The result of such a concatenation is implementation-defined.

The emphasis is my own.

Can anyone confirm if this is in the standard as indicated by cppreference?

**EDIT**

By doesn't like, I mean I get the following error:

```
error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings
```

Comment: FWIW, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86888ehe.aspx) for that error does say you're not allowed to concatenate wide and non-wide string literals. So this looks like a C++11 feature that's not yet been implemented. You should file a bug report on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Does MSVS2013 *claim* to (fully) support C++2011? By all means report it, but it's not clear that it's really a *bug* as such.

Comment: @KeithThompson, from what I've gathered, they are still progressing towards C++11 and C++14, though there wasn't any info as to if this is on there list of things to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2003 ISO C++ standard, section 2.13.4p3, says:

> In translation phase 6 (2.1), adjacent narrow string literals are
>   concatenated and adjacent wide string literals are concatenated.  If a
>   narrow string literal token is adjacent to a wide string literal
>   token, the behavior is undefined.  Characters in concatenated strings
>   are kept distinct.

The 2011 standard, section 2.14.5p13, says:

> In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are
>   concatenated. If both string literals have the same *encoding-prefix*,
>   the resulting concatenated string literal has that *encoding-prefix*.
>   If one string literal has no *encoding-prefix*, it is treated as a
>   string literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand. If a
>   UTF-8 string literal token is adjacent to a wide string literal token,
>   the program is ill-formed. Any other concatenations are conditionally
>   supported with implementation-defined behavior.

So the sequence `L"boo " "hoo"` has undefined behavior in C2003 but is well defined and equivalent to `L"boohoo"` in C2011.

I can't tell from the information you've given us whether MSVS2013 conforms to C++11. You say it "doesn't like" the construct, but if the dislike is expressed as a non-fatal warning and the semantics are as specified in the 2011 standard, then it could be conforming.

Can you update the question to show the diagnostic message?

Comment: Both answers are good.  I only gave it to you since you were a minute faster in the posting. :)

Comment: @Adrian: And I mentioned that it's undefined behavior under the 2003 standard.

Answer (score 4):

From N3797, *§2.14.5/13* [lex.string]

> In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are
>   concatenated. If both string literals have the same encoding-prefix,
>   the resulting concatenated string literal has that encoding-prefix. If
>   one string literal has no encoding-prefix, it is treated as a string
>   literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand.

The table following that even lists an example that's the same as what you've shown

```
// Source         Means
L"a" "b"          L"ab"
```

So I'd say your code is well-formed and this is a VisualStudio bug.