# Error in histograms C++ root

Tags: c++, histogram, root-framework

I have this line of code in C++ (root):

```
    void TMTrackAnalyzer::beginJob(){
    hisStubsVsR_.insert( pair< ObjectType, TH1F* > (InputData, dirs_.at(InputData).make<TH1F>("StubsVsR","; radius (cm); No. stubs in tracker",1200,0.,120.)));
    }
```

which basically fills a histogram, sets the range of the histogram, label and title. Actually I fill more histograms in this function, but I put here just one for simplicity. And for each of them I get these errors:

```
    expected primary-expression before '(' token
    expected primary-expression before ',' token
    expected primary-expression before ')' token
    expected primary-expression before '>' token
    left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
```

InputData is the directory where I want to save the histograms. Do anyone has any idea what is wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.  Notice how the string isn't all red?  You need to escape nested quotes in strings.

Comment: Are you compiling the code with root, or with an external compiler (e.g. gcc or clang)? Do the error messages include a column number to show exactly which `(`, `,`, `)`, `>` it is complaining about?

Comment: @NathanOliver but why is this happening? I have the right number of quotations.

Comment: Looks like the multiple adjacent string literals it throwing of the formatter.  Should the parameter list be `"StubsVsR","; radius (cm);" "No. stubs" "i\
n tracker",1200,0.,120.`?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot put two string literals subsequently, like this: ("str1" "str2").
Put all together or separate it with comma.
Your line must be one of the following, to compile:

```
hisStubsVsR_.insert( pair< ObjectType, TH1F* > (InputData, dirs_.at(InputData).make<TH1F>("StubsVsR","; radius (cm); No. stubs in tracker",1200,0.,120.)));

hisStubsVsR_.insert( pair< ObjectType, TH1F* > (InputData, dirs_.at(InputData).make<TH1F>("StubsVsR","; radius (cm);", "No. stubs", "in tracker",1200,0.,120.)));
```

Comment: But I don't have it that way

Comment: @Vanderson. FYI, in c++ you can put string literals next to each other. "str1" "str2" is the same as "str1str2".

Comment: There are compilers that dont't accept It: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687283/string-literal-concatenation-fails-when-prefixed-string-is-adjacent-to-non-prefi